# Find specific data within 365 days

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table that has various historical data on where certain people worked and lived over a 50 year period. To simplify, each record has a date, a person_id, an address_id and a boolean work true or false and a second boolean residence true or false. The data is sporadic enough that there aren't many matches. The person could have lived at his place of work, although this can be ignored for the purposes of this question.

I want to find each instance when there is a work address and a residence address within a one year span for a person. Of course the person could have changed jobs and residences over the 50 year period.

A summary of the information can be seen at: https://secure-shore-68966.herokuapp.com/connections.

Rails program is at https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5/

Is there a way to do this with SQL/Active Record? I can see iterating over each record and finding any occurrences with plus or minus six months of each record for that person. But I'm hoping for a SQL way. I want to draw a line on a map between each pair.

Table:

    `CREATE TABLE public.years
    (
      id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('years_id_seq'::regclass),
      year_date date,
      created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
      updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
      resto boolean,
      resid boolean,
      source text,
      person_id integer,
      location_id integer,
      title character varying,
      notes text,
      resto_name character varying,
      ref_link character varying,
      ref_url character varying,
      snippet_file_name character varying,
      snippet_content_type character varying,
      snippet_file_size integer,
      snippet_updated_at timestamp without time zone,
      CONSTRAINT years_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
      CONSTRAINT fk_rails_8fc1813509 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
          REFERENCES public.people (id) MATCH SIMPLE
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT fk_rails_e1624dbb3f FOREIGN KEY (location_id)
          REFERENCES public.locations (id) MATCH SIMPLE
          ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
    )`

So for any `person_id` entry, if `resid` is `true` is there `resto` `true` within plus or minus six months (`year_date`).

Comment: The one year span is form now (CurrentDate), or from a specific date?

Answer (score 0):

From a date for the item. If I were to iterate I'd look at the date for that line and for that person find if they had any entries within six months. With added proviso that if the item was resid true the +- six months was resto true.